# How to make reusable library/package in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

New to typescript and learning angular2. I can create an app and display it in the browser, but I thougt it would be best to develop the app by importing libaries and using them in the main-app.

Is there a way to make reusable library in angular? I cannot seem to find any help on this.

For example, given the following app structure, if I wish to remove and place the shared directory assets in a **shared-lib**, how can I accomplish this? What do I place in the package.json etc?

```
├── admin
│   ├── home-dashboard.component.ts
│   ├── home-dashboard.component.html
│   ├── home-dashboard.component.css
│   ├── home-dashboard.component.spec.ts
│   ├── login.component.ts
│   ├── login.component.spec.ts
│   ├── admin.model.ts
│   ├── user-management.service.ts
│   └── order-management.service.ts
├── shared
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── avatar.component.ts
│   │   ├── avatar.component.html
│   │   ├── login-form.component.ts
│   │   ├── login-form.component.html
│   │   ├── login-form.component.css
│   │   └── login-form.component.spec.ts
│   ├── directives
│   │   ├── form-validator.directive.ts
│   │   ├── form-validator.directive.spec.ts
│   │   ├── tooltip.directive.ts
│   │   └── tooltip.directive.spec.ts
│   └── services
│       └── authorization.service.ts
├── pipes
│   ├── format-order-name.pipe.ts
│   └── format-order-name.pipe.spec.ts
└── shop
    ├── components
    │   ├── edit-profile.component.ts
    │   ├── edit-profile.component.html
    │   ├── edit-profile.component.css
    │   ├── edit-profile.component.spec.ts
    │   ├── home.component.ts
    │   ├── home.component.spec.ts
    │   ├── home.component.html
    │   ├── register.component.ts
    │   └── register.component.spec.ts
    ├── models
    │   ├── shopping-cart.model.ts
    │   ├── shopping-item.model.ts
    │   └── user.model.ts
    └── services
        └── checkout.service.ts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you were to be putting something in package.json, then you would have to make it an `npm package` (something that would be npm install'd). You might need to make it a private npm package also. (Which isn't free)

I think what you're looking for is the ability to make it it's own `import`?

As in:

```
import { Avatar, Tooltip } from 'shared-lib';
```

If you just had everything wrapped in a large module that exported everything (and was still within your project structure somewhere)

You could do something like:

```
import { Avatar, Tooltip } from '../../shared-lib'; // or wherever the large index.js module is found.
```

That *index.js* module needs to import all the specific components / directives / etc you want into it, and then export them all individually. Voila you'll be able to access them via the `{ Avatar }`.

Comment: npm also allows you to reference github repos. You could definitely have it in a separate repo, and then import it using the technique mentioned above.